# How do I prevent a partition on the hard drive from auto-mounting on boot?

Tags: osx-lion, mount, boot, hard-drive

I've tried this:

Having the UUID for the volume (seen on disk utilities) to hide during the mount process, from an admin account edit the /etc/fstab file:

> sudo pico /etc/fstab/

Add a line with the UUID for your volume and the mounting point information, for example:

> UUID=EXAMPLE-5558-3BB3-9FA9-EXAaaaaAMPLE  none  hfs  rw,noauto

Save the file.

But it does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: Even if you're choosing not to mount something, shouldn't it have a mount point of some sort, instead of "none"?  Also, your entry is missing the pass/dump "0 0" values at the end of the fstab entry line.  I don't know if it makes a difference, but I think I've heard of "poorly formed" fstab lines being ignored.

Answer (score 2):

Late entry ... But I've had issues with fstab entries failing when using UUID on Lion 10.7.2 ... Seems odd but using labels in the entries works fine.

For instance the following would simply be ingnored ...

```
UUID=EXAMPLE-5558-3BB3-9FA9-EXAaaaaAMPLE none hfs rw,noauto
```

But this would work ...

```
LABEL=EXAMPLE\040\LABEL none hfs ro,noauto,nouser 0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

If commenting out the mounting line in fstab doesn't work, it may be another domain or boot-script written custom for your environment that is a second stage mount. You could possibly setup a boot script to unmount anything using that UUID on boot?

Comment: I've made an automator app that unmounts the desired disk, that seems to work. (It would be cleaner not having the disk mounted un then unmounted every time though). Thank you.

Comment: @juezyparte app or bash script? :P

Comment: App, I have to say that does the job but reports an error (still works it's a false error message)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add R/W privileges to /private/etc/autofs.conf and edit that I believe.

Comment: When "walking" on terminal I'm not confident about "touching" here and there... ¿Would you please tell me how?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little launch daemon that does the job on Lion - blocks auto mount of volumes with specified labels: https://github.com/nanoant/mountblockd

It requires Xcode/developer tools to be installed.